# google compute engine static ip issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up a security scan for a URL hosted on Google Compute Engine.

The domain is pointing to an IP on GCP.

I have recently changed the IP to be static.

The error I get is:

"One of the starting URLs is mapped to an IP address that is not reserved as static for this project; check its DNS settings and External IP addresses section"

Is it just that it will take time for the IP to be fully registered as static or do I need to restart the instance or something?

Comment: The word 'reserved' in the error message makes me think of DCHP reservations.  Perhaps the platform wants you to reserve your static IPs so the DHCP system does not attempt to issue those IPs.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you need to set the target to an external static IP that host the web server, After [reserving an Static External IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address), and using it, make sure **In use by** field show your instance name other wise it will give you the error message as you have:

```
"One of the starting URLs is mapped to an IP address that is not reserved as static for this project; check its DNS settings and External IP addresses section"
```

When you assign a reserved static External IP to an instance and this instance was having another ephemeral external IP, you may need to restart the instance.(I did run through this and solved by restarting the instance).

The steps above will not be necessary when [promoting ephemeral  External IP to Static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you static ip reserved for same project. please refer [Cloud Security Scanner for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/docs/scanning-compute-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Go to VM INSTANCES. Click on the Instance you have problem with. Click Edit. Scroll down and check if your instance is properly using your static IP. If not, just assign that IP.